# Scaling a Three.js geometry only up

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm trying to scale the geometries y-axis. This made my cube scale both up and down. I think mesh.transformY works to animate the cube up half of the scaling value. This would make it look like the cube just scaled upwards. Are there other solutions for this?

```
    var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(1, 1, 1);
    var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
        color: 0xffffff
    }));

    mesh.position.set(0, 2, 0);
    mesh.scale.set(0.98, 0.95, 0.992);
    mesh.castShadow = true;
    scene.add(mesh);

    var tween = new TWEEN.Tween(mesh.scale)tween.to({y: 2}, 1000)
    tween.easing(TWEEN.Easing.Elastic.InOut);
    tween.yoyo(true);
    tween.start();
```

Comment: This is because 3D object positions in Three.js are at the center of the object. So if you wish to "scale upwards" you will need to move the object up while also scaling it. Though there may be an easier way to achieve what you want.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The usual case of your question is something on a 'ground', like a 'person' mesh, that shall always have its feet on the ground whatever its size. There are two ways for that.

- The way Evilzebra proposed in the comment. Based on the height of your mesh you can implement it easily : as you wrote, when scaling in `y`, the mesh will get half taller both on top and bottom. So you just have to move its position to `height * scale / 2` :

  ```
  function scaleY ( mesh, scale ) {
      mesh.scale.y = scale ;
      if( ! mesh.geometry.boundingBox ) mesh.geometry.computeBoundingBox();
      var height = mesh.geometry.boundingBox.max.y - mesh.geometry.boundingBox.min.y;
      //height is here the native height of the geometry
      //that does not change with scaling. 
      //So we need to multiply with scale again
      mesh.position.y = height * scale / 2 ;
  }
  ```
- Another way is to move the origin of the coordinates (local space) at the bottom of the geometry, so the position is not changed. For that you have to move the origin of the geometry to the lowest `y` coordinate. You will then be able to change your scale at will with the native ThreeJS method :

  ```
  function originToBottom ( geometry ) {

      //1. Find the lowest `y` coordinate
      var shift = geometry.boundingBox ? geometry.boundingBox.min.y : geometry.computeBoundingBox().min.y;

      //2. Then you translate all your vertices up 
      //so the vertical origin is the bottom of the feet :
      for ( var i = 0 ; i < geometry.vertices.length ; i++ ) {
          geometry.vertices[ i ].y -= shift;
      }
      //or as threejs implements (WestLangley's answer) : 
      geometry.translate( 0, -shift, 0);

      //finally
      geometry.verticesNeedUpdate = true;
  }
  ```

Answer (score 11):

If you want your geometry to scale only "up", all you need to do is make sure the "bottom" of your geometry passes through the origin. In your case, you can use the `translate()` method like so:

```
var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 1, 1, 1 );
geometry.translate( 0, 0.5, 0 );

var tween = new TWEEN.Tween( mesh.scale ).to( { y: 2 }, 1000 );
tween.start();
```

The bottom of the box will remain fixed, and the box's height will change.

three.js r.73

Comment: Perfect. This should be marked as the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

Since this is, in my case, the first item on Google on how to scale a geometry I'll post my function to alter a geometry.

```
function _alterGeometry(geometry, opt) {

    var toAlter = [];

    var matrixMultiplier = function (mtx) {
        var matrix = new THREE.Matrix4();
        mtx.forEach(function (m, index) {
            matrix = new THREE.Matrix4().multiplyMatrices(matrix, m);
        });
        return matrix;
    };

    if (opt.position)
        toAlter.push(new THREE.Matrix4().setPosition(new THREE.Vector3(opt.position.x, opt.position.y, opt.position.z)));

    if (opt.rotation && opt.rotation.x)
        toAlter.push(new THREE.Matrix4().makeRotationAxis(new THREE.Vector3(1, 0, 0), opt.rotation.x));

    if (opt.rotation && opt.rotation.y)
        toAlter.push(new THREE.Matrix4().makeRotationAxis(new THREE.Vector3(0, 1, 0), opt.rotation.y));

    if (opt.rotation && opt.rotation.z)
        toAlter.push(new THREE.Matrix4().makeRotationAxis(new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 1), opt.rotation.z));

    if (opt.scale)
        toAlter.push(new THREE.Matrix4().scale(opt.scale));

    geometry.applyMatrix(matrixMultiplier(toAlter));
    return geometry;

}
```